# I just built a non-measurable set without the axiom of choice, where is my mistake?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us define $p_k$ the $k\text{-th}$ decimal. Let us define, whet it exists, the limit of the mean of the $k\text{-th}$ first decimal.

$$c_p = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{1}^{n}{p_k}}{n}$$

Let us define

$$R_5 = \{r \in [0, 1] | c_r = 5\}$$

$R_5$ is not empty, since $0.55555... \in R_q$.

It is also dense in $[0,1]$. (if $x < y$, you can find the first different decimal, and replace the end with 55555... on either $x$ or $y$, depending on their next decimal : e.g. if $x=0.4566666..$, $y=0.457777...$, choose $0.457555...$).

$R_5$ is uncountable, since you can use the Cantor diagonalization process, and build the $q_k$ decimal as 5 if the $q_k$ decimal of the number it is compare to is not a 5, and alternate between 1 and 9 if it is a 5.

$R_5^{c}$ is also uncountable and dense in $[0, 1]$, and even in every $[a, b]$, with $0 \le a < b \le 1$.

Since I can build some $R_p$ for each $p \in ]1, 8[$ using a similar trick, and they are trivially disjoint, $\mu(R_p) = 0$ is the only possible solution. But since it is dense and uncountable, I cannot apply a similar trick as what is used to measure the Cantor's set or the rational set.

It seems like $R_5$ is not Lebesgue-measurable (the outer Lebesgue measure is not equal to the inner Lebesgue measure), and was designed without the use of the axiom of choice. But, as said in a lot of answer, this is impossible (with the ZF axioms alone, every set of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable), see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set. So, where is my mistake ?

Comment: Can you prove that your set is not Lebesgue measurable? The set of all irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ is also uncountable and dense but that doesn't make it non-measurable.

Comment: This is uncountable and dense in [0,1], and its opposite is also uncountable and dense. I don't see a way to prove that $\mu(R_5) = 0$ Also, it must necessarily be equal to 0, because for each real $p \in ]1, 9[$ I can build such a $R_p$ subset of $[0, 1]$ (and they are all disjoint).

Comment: Uncountability has nothing to do with measure.

Comment: Since it is dense and uncountable, I can't apply the same kind of trick that one apply for the Cantor's set, which is not dense. I can't find a countable list of open intervals of arbitrary size to either encompass $R_5$ or $R_5^{c}$

Comment: Your mistake seems to be in an unjustified claim of non-measurability. Can you explain why you think your set is non-measurable in more detail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$R_5$ is a Borel set, and therefore Lebesgue measurable. Define $g_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor10^kx\right\rfloor-10\lfloor 10^{k-1}x\rfloor$ and consider $u(x)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)$ and $v(x)=\liminf_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)$. These are Borel functions because they are the liminf and limsup of Borel functions, and $R_5=v^{-1}\{5\}\cap u^{-1}\{5\}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I had absolutely not in mind this trick, of expliciting this set as a reciprocical image of a Borel function !!

Comment: @DoeJowns Well, being Borel is extra. I was aiming for the function to be measurable. But the reality is that you can often take for granted that sets and functions defined explicitly in terms of actual mathematics turn out to be Borel. You need some form of choice to prove that non-Borel sets exist too (for instance, it is consistent wit ZF that $\Bbb R$ is union of a countable family of countable sets).

Comment: @Doe Jowns: Not only are they Borel functions, but they are among the simplest Borel functions. I believe they're at level $2$ in the $\omega_1$ hierarchy of Borel/Baire functions. So even among Borel functions they are like the countable ordinal $2$ as compared to other countable ordinals one could consider, such as ${\omega}^{\omega}$ or $\epsilon_0$ or $\epsilon_{\omega}$ or the $\omega^{\omega}$'th ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\epsilon_{\alpha} = \alpha$ or [the much larger countable ordinals described here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/large-countable-ordinals-part-3/).

Answer (score 1):

User Mees de Vries (if I recall correctly) had posted an answer, with some minor errors, that explained Lebesgue measurability of $R_5$ in terms of [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). Since it's been a day since and since that approach allows the actual computation of the measure of $R_5$ and many similar sets, I'm posting as community wiki a version with the corrections needed and a few sources.

It is known ([here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00591-021-00303-w)'s a proof by by Edmund Weitz, based on an idea by Hausdorff; to my understanding, it works just fine in ZF) that almost all real numbers, in the sense of Lebesgue measure, are normal.

Now let $N$, $N_b$ and $S_b$ denote the sets of normal, base-$b$ normal and base-$b$ simply normal numbers, and call $R^b_p$ the same construction you've done, but in base $b$. The following inclusions are easily proved: $$R^b_{(b-1)/2}\supseteq[0,1]\cap S_b\supseteq[0,1]\cap N_b\supseteq[0,1]\cap N$$

Therefore we know, for instance, that $R^{10}_{4.5}$ has Lebesgue measure $1$, and therefore that $R^{10}_5$ is a null set. More generally, all the $R^b_p$ are Lebesgue measurable and their measure is $1$ if $p=\frac{b-1}2$ and $0$ otherwise.

If we consider that $\bigcap_{b\ge2}R^b_{(b-1)/2}\supseteq[0,1]\cap N$, we can see that any asymptotic condition, no matter how strange it may look, on the average of the digits of a number ends up producing a null set, and therefore a Lebesgue measurable one, as soon as in at least one base $b$ it excludes convergence to $\frac{b-1}2$.

Comment: Thank you ! I did not know this notion, which completely match and extend what I tried to define. Reinventing the wheel, as usual...